# substitute complex regular expression in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to substitute text to a word using gsub. For example:

My text is:
I will add [USER=1234]@banana1[/USER] to the chat

My  desired output is:
I will add usermention  to the chat

Basically ,  I  want to substitute
[USER=1234]@banana1[/USER] to
usermention

I have tried the following code but  unsuccessfully:

```
text=c("I ​will add [USER=1234]@banana1[/USER] to the chat")
replace_user=gsub("\\[user.*?\\/user\\]","usermention",text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it with

```r
> gsub("\\[user.*?/user]","usermention",text, ignore.case=TRUE)
[1] "I ​will add usermention to the chat"
```

Note that `/` is not any special in a TRE regex pattern, same is with `]` outside a bracket expression, so no need to escape it.

Since you have `USER` and not `user` in the original string, you need the `ignore.case=TRUE` argument.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/tITG04/1).

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/DoL3wz):

```r
text=c("I will add [USER=1234]@banana1[/USER] to the chat"
gsub("\\[user.*?/user]","usermention",text, ignore.case=TRUE)
## => [1] "I will add usermention to the chat"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
 sub("\\[.*\\]", "usermention", text)
[1] "I ​will add usermention to the chat"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this , I've done this before but the problem is that there are other regular expressions similar to that one that i need to substitute, for example : [url]http://www.google.com/[/url]  into urllink This is why I have not used that .